# How to get a function value without running the whole function again

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to save the value of the list that was inputted earlier without having to reinput it again when I call the function to save it.

Preferrably without using OOP as it is currently outside of my learning module but if its inevitable then it is welcomed as well for self learning.

```
def createQuiz():
    quiz = []
    for i in range(2):
        quiz.append(str(i+1) + ') ' + input('Please input Question ' + str(i+1) + ':\n'))
        for j in range(4):
            quiz.append(chr(97+j) + '. ' + input('Please input option ' + str(j+1) + ':\n'))
        quiz.append('Answer: ' + input('Please input Answer(A,B,C,D):\n'))
    return quiz


def saveQuiz():
    with open('quiz.txt', 'w') as file:
        for i in createQuiz():
            file.write(i)
            file.write('\n')


def menu():
        userinput = int(input())
        if userinput == 1:
            createQuiz()
        elif userinput == 2:
            saveQuiz()
```

I am expecting for it to save the value in the list into the file, however when I run saveQuiz() it would run the whole createQuiz() asking me to re input the value again.

Comment: `import json` and `json.dump(file, my_list)` will be a much easier approach than reparsing that file in the future as it will support `json.load(file)`. Json is designed arround lists and dicts making it a great way to store data.

Comment: Thanks I will look it up

Comment: concerning the question, so you'd like to save to the file every time there is an input, correct? That would seem inefficient with regard to memory management. Nothing wrong with collecting some results and saving them when everything is done.

Comment: So I edited the question a bit to be a bit more similar to the final product so as according to the question. The first one is to make a function that receives user input and saves it into a list. The second one is to make a function that saves the value into a file. The problem with my code currently is that when I run the saveQuiz() function it would rerun the whole code asking me to reinput the value again. But instead what I wanted is to run the first one to input the value into the list and when I input 2 on the choice it would just save the info on the list into the file.

Answer (score 0):

your line

```
for i in createQuiz():
```

was calling for a new instance of quiz and had no reference to the quiz you made before. I think you meant to do this:

```
def createQuiz():
    quiz = []
    for i in range(2):
        quiz.append(str(i+1) + ') ' + input('Please input Question ' + str(i+1) + ':\n'))
        for j in range(2):
            quiz.append(chr(97+j) + '. ' + input('Please input option ' + str(j+1) + ':\n'))
        quiz.append('Answer: ' + input('Please input Answer(A,B,C,D):\n'))
    return quiz


def saveQuiz(quiz):
    with open('quiz.txt', 'w') as file:
        for i in quiz:
            file.write(i)
            file.write('\n')

quiz_instance = createQuiz()
saveQuiz(quiz_instance)
```

which gave me a file 'quiz.txt' containing

```
1) q1
a. a
b. b
Answer: b
2) q2
a. a
b. b
Answer: a
```

Comment: I thought as I already used return quiz to return the quiz list in createQuiz(), when I refer to createQuiz() in saveQuiz() it would return the value of list quiz. Btw to reiterate my question what I wanted to do was so that when I run my saveQuiz() it won't run the whole createQuiz() function including asking for input all over again but rather just save what is currently within the list quiz into the file. I thought of using global variable for that however a lot of post mention that it is not recommended.

Comment: On the one hand you talk about `createQuiz()` as if it is an object, on the other hand you talk about `createQuiz()` as a function. Those are two different things. functions are not built to store data. The output however (which you give by return quiz) can be used for other purposes like saving it. And that is exactly what the `saveQuiz(quiz)` function is doing in my code.

Comment: I hope this answered your question. If it did, you might accept my (or any other) answer as an accepted answer using the checkbox